# How to get paths of folders that has image or video

Tags: java, android, directory, gallery, photos

I want to create an android gallery app .

How to scan and get paths of folders that includes photos or videos .

I used this code and worked . but when i compare it with Quickpic Gallery in play store , i see the count of folders in my app is less than Quickpic folders

Do you see any problem in this code ?

```
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = ba.context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
            null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int data = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        int displayName = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        imageFolders = new HashMap<>();
        do {
            String imageAddress = cursor.getString(data);
            String imageName = cursor.getString(displayName);
            String folderAddress = imageAddress.substring(0,
                    imageAddress.lastIndexOf(imageName) - 1);

            if (!imageFolders.containsKey(folderAddress)) {
                imageFolders.put(folderAddress, imageAddress);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        for (String str : imageFolders.keySet()) {

            ba.raiseEventFromDifferentThread(
                    null,
                    null,
                    0,
                    "result",
                    true,
                    new Object[] { String.format("%s", str),
                            String.format("%s", imageFolders.get(str)) });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Scan all the folders. Check to see if there are photos or videos in them. Make a list.

Comment: @JasonC  please see my second answer.

Comment: Edit you question and add your answer. Then remove your answer.

Comment: @Sadeq "Post *Answer*" is not for adding details to questions. There's a reason questions have an *edit* button underneath them.

Comment: Ok , i edited my post , excuse me .

Answer (score 2):

this way you can find all video and image parents.

```
ArrayList<String> allFolder;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> listImageByFolder;
    ArrayList<String> allVideoFolder;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> listVideoByFolder;
```

**find all images folder path**
        private void getImageFolderList() {

```
        String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN };
        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images, projection, // Which
                                                                    // columns
                                                                    // to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
        );
        ArrayList<String> imagePath;
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            String bucket, date;
            int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                if (!allFolder.contains(bucket)) {
                    allFolder.add(bucket);
                }
                imagePath = listImageByFolder.get(bucket);
                if (imagePath == null) {
                    imagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                imagePath.add(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
                listImageByFolder.put(bucket, imagePath);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

**find all videos folder path**

```
    private void getVideoFolderList() {
        String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN };
        Uri images = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images, projection, // Which
                                                                    // columns
                                                                    // to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
        );
        ArrayList<String> imagePath;
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            String bucket, date;
            int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                if (!allVideoFolder.contains(bucket)) {
                    allVideoFolder.add(bucket);
                }
                imagePath = listVideoByFolder.get(bucket);
                if (imagePath == null) {
                    imagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                imagePath.add(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
                listVideoByFolder.put(bucket, imagePath);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , its work like a charm .

but when we have 2 folders with same name in ExternalStorage and SDcard Like (Camera folder),  this code returns one of them .

Comment: @Sadeq Nameni You can use BUCKET_ID for this, as bucket id is unique for each folder.

Answer (score 2):

i can see you are trying to get the folder names of all folders containing video files the answer given by @prakash ubhadiya is good an works but for the problem that if the are many of such folders with same name the function will keep only one and ignore the rest, below i have modified his fuction to return not only the folder names but also the folder absolute path in case you will want to use this to get all the video files in that specific folder, i have created a class called `floderFacer` the holds the folder name and the folder adsolute path, done this way no folders with same names will be ignored below is the class

```
public class folderFacer {

    private String path;
    private String folderName;

    public folderFacer(){

    }

    public folderFacer(String path, String folderName) {
        this.path = path;
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getFolderName() {
        return folderName;
    }

    public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }
}
```

now below is the modified fuction that will return the folder names and paths in a `folderFacer` object all in an `ArrayList<folderFacer>`

```
private ArrayList<folderFacer> getVideoPaths(){
        ArrayList<folderFacer> videoFolders = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> videoPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri allVideosuri = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_ID};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(allVideosuri, projection, null, null, null);

        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{

                folderFacer folds = new folderFacer();

              String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String folder = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
              String datapath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));

              String folderpaths =  datapath.replace(name,"");
                if (!videoPaths.contains(folderpaths)) {
                    videoPaths.add(folderpaths);

                    folds.setPath(folderpaths);
                    folds.setFolderName(folder);
                    videoFolders.add(folds);
                }

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < videoFolders.size();i++){

            Log.d("video folders",videoFolders.get(i).getFolderName()+" and path = "+videoFolders.get(i).getPath());

        }

        return videoFolders;
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: is there any github example ? or can you make a with this https://github.com/abdullah432/SAFProject

Comment: hi @sanojlawrence

Comment: how do i combine the github with your code ?. to display folder name of file ?

Comment: I created an android class library for all accessing Media Content in the MediaStore with ease, the library is at the third version now, and am currently working on another release and also creating a Xamarin.Android equivalent,  here is the library on GitHub  https://github.com/CodeBoy722/MediaFacer, make sure to read the Medium article in the Readme.md  to understand how it works

Comment: using the library is very easy, follow the steps in the Readme.md to add it to your project first

Comment: MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA is deprecated. any other solution to do this ?