# How to scan through all the directories and get the list of file names and path that ends with given extension in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have stuck with a requirement. I need to list all the files that ends with .txt and some time .srt etc.

I have to show the list of files after scanning through all the directories that are present.

I know how to scan files in a directory.

```
val dir = File(dirName)

        return dir.listFiles(object : FilenameFilter() {
            override fun accept(dir: File?, filename: String): Boolean {
                return filename.endsWith(".txt")
            }
        })
```

But I want to scan all the directories for files that ends with specified extension.

And also I need to edit it. So, Some how I need to get their path.

How can I achieve this in kotlin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567419/list-files-recursively-in-kotlin this may help

Comment: @HED I typed `File("/tmp").walkTopDown().forEach { Log.d("log", "$it") }` in on create of the view. and it prints nothing. I  need  more explanation for this. Thank you.

Comment: Im not aware that there would be a /tmp directory on an Android device. Try with another directory.

Comment: @blackapps I think you didn't understood the problem. I need to search all the directories that are present. ex: movies - downloads etc. If i specify a directory that will search only on that particular directory like "downloads". I need  a way to mention root folder name which contains all these directories. and loop through

Comment: @blackapps may be this will be the answer but i'm not getting it properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484758/how-to-get-paths-of-folders-that-has-image-or-video/39485395

Comment: `If i specify a directory that will search only on that particular directory like "downloads".` Even if the downloads directory has subdirectories ans so on? Then you have to make your function recursive.

Comment: @blackapps This is becoming very tough. I will change my requirement itself. Thank you !